# How to gauge away Goldstone bosons in Higgs triplet model?

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm studying the Higgs triplet model (HTM) in which you add a complex $SU(2)$ triplet (represented by a 2x2 matrix) to the standard model higgs sector. The thing is that I don't understand how to explicitly gauge away the goldstone bosons of the theory. I've read many papers that mention this but they never explain how they realize that the goldstone bosons are unphysical and the other particles are physical.

I know that this has to do with a redefinition of the fields through a $SU(2)$ transformation but when it comes time to compute it, I get confused.
I'd really appreciate your answers.